# visualizing crosstab tables with a plot in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, bubble-chart

I saw a plot generated in excel and I was wondering if R could also do it.[image: this picture is essentially a visualization of a crosstab table comparing the days of the week to preferred meals on that day and counting the number of people that fall within those categories]

This picture is essentially a visualization of a crosstab table comparing the days of the week to preferred meals on that day and counting the number of people that fall within those categories.

How I can make a plot like this one?

Comment: Perhaps [my answer here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34778/13474) might help you.

Comment: I am interested in how that chart was made in Excel to start with. Any clues?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using Hadley Wickham's `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)                           

# Set up the vectors                           
days <- c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri")
slots <- c("Coffee/Breakfast","Lunch","Happy Hour","Dinner")

# Create the data frame
df <- expand.grid(days, slots)
df$value <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,NA,NA,1,4,4,7,4,1,5,6,14,5,1)    

#Plot the Data
g <- ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Var2)) + geom_point(aes(size = value), colour = "green") + theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("")
g + scale_size_continuous(range=c(10,30)) + geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

[image]

Do you care that the axis lines go through the circles? Also, the greens are slightly different and the label text is black instead of white.

Comment: it's perfect this way, thank you. just one question, is there a way to change the shapes, the circles look a bit "ruffled" around the edges. Can the function make it a smooth circle? If not then that's okay

Comment: With `ggsave` you can set the dots per inch. The default is 72 dpi, with `ggsave(file="filename.png", dpi=300)` you can set the value for dpi to a higher value. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [ggmosaic package](https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/blob/master/README.md) extends `ggplot` to provide an alternative.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)

# Set up the vectors                           
days <- c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri")
slots <- c("Coffee/Breakfast","Lunch","Happy Hour","Dinner")

# Create the comporessed data frame
df <- expand.grid(days, slots, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
df$value <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,1,4,4,7,4,1,5,6,14,5,1)    
df.expanded <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$value), 1:2]

#Plot the Data
ggplot(data = df.expanded) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Var2,Var1), fill = Var2)) + 
  ggsave("mosaic.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an alternative approach that makes use of the excellent `ggpubr` package:

```r
# Load ggpubr package
library(ggpubr)

## Borrowed from Tommy O'Dell's answer
# Set up the vectors                           
days <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri")
slots <- c("Coffee/Breakfast", "Lunch", "Happy Hour", "Dinner")

# Create the data frame
df <- expand.grid(days, slots)
df$value <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 4, 4, 7, 4, 1, 5, 6, 14, 5, 1)

## Plot the data (my contribution)
ggballoonplot(
  data = df, 
  x = "Var1", 
  y = "Var2",
  size = "value",
  size.range = c(10, 20), 
  fill = "green",
  show.label = TRUE, 
  rotate.x.text = FALSE, 
  legend = "none"
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>