# How to generate a graphical matrix from a dataset where each variable has been specified as binary TRUE/FALSE – convert data into required format?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, matrix, binary

thanks in advance for your help

I am trying to generate a graphical matrix to illustrate the number of scientific papers reporting a certain biodiversity indicator for each type of agroforestry system.

**CONTEXT**

Using descriptive summary statistics to analyse a large database on silvoarable agroforestry on aspects of agroforestry systems, biodiversity and ecosystem services, as part of a systematic mapping review.

**GOAL**

To illustrate the number of scientific papers reporting on various biodiversity indicators for each agroforestry system. To do so I would like to generate a graphical matrix (e.g. Adjacency matrix, Balloon plot), that shows the number of papers reporting on each agroforestry system and each type of biodiversity indicator. See also the attached figures.

*Exemplary sketch of the desired outcome*

[image: Exemplary sketch of the desired outcome]

*Inspirational example from Ditzler et al. (2021)*

[image: Inspirational example from Ditzler et al. (2021)]

**DATA**

The database consists of hundreds of variables including everything from the location of the study to the specific biodiversity and ecosystem services addressed in the study. Here I have made a subset of the database that only includes the unique paper ID (ID.P), AC.TYPE (alley cropping type) and eight biodiversity variables (BD).

```
tibble::tribble(
                  ~ID.P, ~ID.S,         ~AC.TYPE, ~BD.SUB.FLORA, ~BD.SUB.FAUNAMACRO, ~BD.SUB.FLORAMICRO, ~BD.SUB.FUNGI, ~BD.SUB.BACTERIA, ~BD.SUB.SOILFAUNA,       ~BD.SUB.SPEC,     ~BD,
                     24,     4,     "NUT.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                     92,     1,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",        "TRUE",             "TRUE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",        "LANDSCAPE",  "TRUE",
                     99,     9,            "SHB",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                     98,     5,            "SHB",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                      7,     2,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                    125,     1, "BIOMASS.ARABLE",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                     45,    17,     "NUT.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                     47,     2, "BIOMASS.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                     69,     2,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",             "TRUE",        "TRUE",           "TRUE",            "TRUE", "MICROBIO.BIOMASS",  "TRUE",
                     14,     1,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                     12,     7, "BIOMASS.ARABLE",        "TRUE",            "FALSE",             "TRUE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE",  "TRUE",
                     51,     1, "BIOMASS.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                    169,     1,             "NA",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                     94,     7,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",        "TRUE",             "TRUE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",        "LANDSCAPE",  "TRUE",
                     49,     1,  "TIMBER.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                     99,     1,            "SHB",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                    131,     1,          "MIXED",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                     45,    13,   "FRUIT.ARABLE",       "FALSE",            "FALSE",            "FALSE",       "FALSE",          "FALSE",           "FALSE",            "FALSE", "FALSE",
                    152,     1, "BIOMASS.ARABLE",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE",
                     37,    29,             "NA",          "NA",               "NA",               "NA",          "NA",             "NA",              "NA",               "NA", "FALSE"
                  )
```

**ISSUE**

My issue is that I cannot convert my dataframe into the required format to generate the graphical matrix I wish to create. I have tried the `xtabs()` and the `aggregate()` function to create a contingency matrix (also called cross table), but without luck (see below). I think it is because my data is based on binary TRUE/FALSE.

```
CrossTab_AC.TYPE_BD <- 
  xtabs(~ AC.TYPE + BD.SUB.FLORA + BD.SUB.FAUNAMACRO + BD.SUB.FAUNAMACRO + BD.SUB.FLORAMICRO + BD.SUB.FUNGI + BD.SUB.BACTERIA + BD.SUB.SOILFAUNA + BD.SUB.SPEC + BD, 
        data = BD_database) %>%
  as.data.frame.table()

CrossTab_AC.TYPE_BD %>%
  sample_n(20) %>%
  head(10)
```

[image]

Then, I try plotting the dataframe using `ggballoonplot()`

```
ggballoonplot(CrossTab_AC.TYPE_BD, x = "AC.TYPE", y = "BD.SUB.FAUNAMACRO",
              size = "Freq", fill = "Freq") +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colors = my_cols_pal_10) +
  guides(size = FALSE)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this is not working..

Instead, I should have a data format like what they use in there ggballoonplot example:

```
car_data
#>         Car  Color Value
#> 1       bmw    red  86.2
#> 2   renault    red 193.5
#> 3  mercedes    red 104.2
#> 4      seat    red 107.8
#> 5       bmw  white 202.9
#> 6   renault  white 127.7
#> 7  mercedes  white  24.1
#> 8      seat  white  58.8
#> 9       bmw silver  73.3
#> 10  renault silver 173.4
#> 11 mercedes silver 121.6
#> 12     seat silver 124.0
#> 13      bmw  green 106.6
#> 14  renault  green  66.6
#> 15 mercedes  green 207.2
#> 16     seat  green 129.9

ggballoonplot(car_data, x = "Car", y = "Color",
              size = "Value", fill = "Value") +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colors = my_cols) +
  guides(size = FALSE)
```

[image: ggballoonplot]

Hence to me, it seems as if the real issue is how to convert the binary TRUE/FALSE dataset into some sort of summarised version that allows me to plot it as a graphical matrix.

I have checked on other posts here on StackOverflow, for instance, this visualizing crosstab tables with a plot in R][6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673584/visualizing-crosstab-tables-with-a-plot-in-r).

Please, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to aggregate this data? Count of `TRUE` values?

Comment: Hi @shs, 

Yes, good question. I want to aggregate my data as the number of TRUE occurrences for each combination of agroforestry type and biodiversity indicator. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all we don't have your colors so I just used the colors from the example. Next you need to convert your data to longer format using `pivot_longer`. After that I converted your true/false to 1/0 which isn't necessary because you only need to count the number of rows by both groups using `group_by` and `summarise` to get the counts to represent in your plot. When that is done, you can just plot it like this

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpubr)

my_cols <- c("#0D0887FF", "#6A00A8FF", "#B12A90FF",
             "#E16462FF", "#FCA636FF", "#F0F921FF")

BD_database %>%
  select(-c(ID.P, ID.S)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -AC.TYPE) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(value == "TRUE" ~ 1,
                           value == "FALSE" ~ 0)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(AC.TYPE, name) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggballoonplot(x = "AC.TYPE", y = "name", size = "n", fill = "n") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = my_cols) +
  guides(size = FALSE)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'AC.TYPE'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> Warning: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> =
#> "none")` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Quinten. I have been attempting to convert it to a long format, but then from there I was stuck on the general methodology. I really appreciate your answer. It is very clear. I apologies for the colours. I wish you a great week ahead.

Comment: Hi again @Quinten, I am sorry to bother you once more but I have just stumbled on an issue related to the code you suggested: It seems like all the number of occurrences of AC.TYPE and Biodiversity indicators are the same for all pairwise situations. And I know for a fact that the data tells another story, so something goes wrong in the way we're pivoting longer. For instance, now the graph shows that the number of studies reporting to be AC.TYPE=BIOMASS.ARABLE and report on BD.SUB.BACTERIA is the same as the one characterized as BIOMASS – BD.SUB.FLORA. But I know this is not the case :-)

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution to my issue by refining the answer from Quinten.**

*Below are my methods for Ecosystem services which essentially is the same as what I wanted for the Biodiversity indicators.*

Firstly, I decided to plot the graphical matrix with ggplot instead of ggballoonplot because the output seems easier for me to wrangle and make neat.

Secondly, I added a `group_by()` piece to the `pivot_longer()` operation with the arguments to group AC.TYPE and the names (Ecosystem Services indicators, ES).

Thirdly, I summarised the occurrences of AC.TYPE – ES pairs (for TRUE's), since changing the TRUE to 1 only counts the 1's and leaves out zeros.

```
try <- 
  ES_database %>%
  filter(AC.TYPE != "NA") %>%
  select(-c(ES)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -AC.TYPE) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(value == "TRUE" ~ 1,
                           value == "FALSE" ~ 0)) %>%
  group_by(AC.TYPE, name) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(value))
```

*This gave me this data table:*

[image]

I could now simply plot it with ggplot() using these lines of code:

```
 ggplot(try, aes(x = AC.TYPE, y = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = count), shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "cornsilk") +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20, guide = "none")
```

[image]

Special thanks to @Quinten who has been very helpful!